# Input string was not in a correct format vb.net/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here's my formview..

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="recid">
<EditItemTemplate>
RECID:
<asp:TextBox ID="recid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RECID") %>' ReadOnly="true" />
<br />
SHIPPER:
<asp:TextBox ID="shipper" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SHIPPER") %>' />
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
&nbsp;
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

here's my sqldatasource1

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM IMPORT WHERE (RECID = ?)"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE IMPORT SET SHIPPER=@shipper WHERE RECID=@recid" >
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="RECID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="recid" Type="Int32" />
<asp:Parameter Name="shipper" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, my problem is that everytime I update the page, this is the error Input string was not in a correct format.

I tried changing the @recid in the UpdateCommand into a constant UpdateCommand="UPDATE IMPORT SET SHIPPER=@shipper WHERE RECID=11186" this worked well, the update was successful.

I think the @recid is being treated as a string here in the UpdateCommand. Can someone please help me? What do I need to do in order to change the data type of @recid to Integer?

Thanks!

Comment: What is data type of RECID in database?

Comment: hi! RECID is integer, auto increment in the database, it is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to fix is to bind `raceid` with the textbox like below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="recid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RECID") %>' ReadOnly="true" />
```

Now there's a question about provider. In select command you have used `RACEID = ?`, `?` is used for `OleDb` or `Odbc`. If you are using any of them, you have to change Update Command to this:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE IMPORT SET SHIPPER=? WHERE RECID=?"
```

And UpdateParameters to this (Notice their order):

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="shipper" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="recid" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

I would recommend reading this MSDN article: [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you so much for this one sir! :) i've been having a hard time fixing this problem for a week i think? my question is that why is it, instead of BIND, it was EVAL? but then again, thank you so much!

Comment: `Eval` is one way binding, to display data. `Bind` works both way, from source to control and control to source.